# Can't knit in R markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

Recently I was doing a course in Coursera and faced the problem while doing R markdown.  When I run the code in the console it works just fine however, when I knit it, the rmarkdown only show text in the code chunk as below.

I  run this in console and it work just fine:
[image]

But when i knit the code appear as text:
[image]

When I hit the green arrow it appears like there are some error going on:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The bottom screenshot you provided is not an R code chunk. It does not have the proper header. R code chunks in an R markdown file must be formatted like this:

````
```{r}
R code goes here
```
````